# Linspace spliting in Numpy or Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How linspace in pandas splitting values in the range.

In the given code I was splitting range from 1 t0 10. if we split these values manually suppose I will do (1+10)//5  == 2.2.
How pandas is splitting it in intervals of 2.25

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ser = pd.Series(np.linspace(1,10,5))
print(ser)
```

> ```
> 0          1.00
>
> 1          3.25
>
> 2          5.50
>
> 3          7.75
>
> 4          10.00
>
> dtype: float64
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Your "manual splitting" is incorrect. Firstly, to find the difference between the two endpoints, you should do subtraction, not addition, e.g. `abs(1 - 10)`, not `1 + 10`.

Also, though you have 5 points, there are actually only four intervals: 1st to 2nd, 2nd to 3rd, 3rd to 4th, 4th to 5th.

Thus, the proper calculation is `abs(1 - 10) / 4` = `(10 - 1) / 4` = `9 / 4` = `2.25`.

More generally, the split distance for `np.linspace(a, b, n)` is

```
abs(a - b) / (n - 1)
```